# How to get multiple parameters with same name from a URL in PHP and insert all records into table

Tags: php, mysql, url, insert

I'm using MySQL query to insert multiple records into table.
In my url i get all records that i have entered but in database it only updates my last record. I am using here onclick function to add new table rows. Any help. 
Here is my code

```
if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    require_once("shine_class.php");
    $s = new shine;
    $s->connection();
    $date1 = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

    $date1= time() ;
    $newdate1 = date("d-m-Y", $date1);


    for ($i=0; $i < count($_GET['finished_product_name']); $i++ )
    {
        $product =$_GET['finished_product_name'];
        $material = $_GET['material_name'];
        $quantity = $_GET['product_quantity'];

        // mysql_query("INSERT INTO material_used (product_name, material_name, product_quantity, date) VALUES ('$a', '$b', '$c','$newdate1')") or die(mysql_error());
        $insert ="insert into material_used set `product_name` = '".$product."', `material_name` = '".$material."', `product_quantity` = '".$quantity."',`date` = '".$newdate1."' ";                   
        $select = mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please write your code here

Comment: where is your query,..if you can paste your query here

Comment: Yes i have pasted my query here,...

Comment: Tell us what you are getting from $_GET..plz write code from where you are posting data

Comment: If i insert two records from table it will show me two records in the URL but updated only one record that is last record my URl look like this                            localhost/shine/usedmaterial.php?finished_product_name=wallhanger-10pin-oscar&material_name=materialA&product_quantity=10&finished_product_name=wallhanger-8pin-oscar&material_name=materialB&product_quantity=20&submit=Add+Now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to assign a value with same name.so your last value replace with the existing value.

for example :your URL look like,

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?finished_product_name=abc&material_name=xxx&finished_product_name=pqr&material_name=yyy
```

so your `$_GET['finished_product_name']` has value is `pqr` not `abc`.

---

If you can change the field name with include `[]`, then PHP will create an array containing all of the matching values:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?id[]=123&version[]=3&id[]=234&version[]=4
```

your URL example like,

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?finished_product_name[]=abc&material_name[]=xxx&finished_product_name[]=pqr&material_name[]=yyy
```

your for loop is :

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['finished_product_name']); $i++ )
{
    $product =$_POST['finished_product_name'][$i];
    $material = $_POST['material_name'][$i];
    $quantity = $_POST'product_quantity'][$i]; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Ajay can you please explain this more how can i update my code to create php array???

Comment: yes, you may add `finished_product_name` into your URL more then one time so your value is replace with existing value.

Comment: In my URL it always shows me all value like this if i have inserted two rows then it will show me like this.....            finished_product_name=wallhanger-10pin-oscar&material_name=materialA&product_quantity=10&finished_product_name=wallhanger-8pin-oscar&material_name=materialB&product_quantity=20&submit=Add+Now    but update only last record like in this case only inserts last record.

Comment: Hey thanks Ajay its working now.... just forget this               for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['finished_product_name']); $i++ )
      {
 $product =$_POST['finished_product_name'][$i];
 $material = $_POST['material_name'][$i];
 $quantity = $_POST['product_quantity'][$i];

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert ="insert into material_used(product_name,material_name,product_quantity,date) VALUES( '$product',  '$material','.$quantiy','$newdate1')
```

Comment: you missed a typo: $quantiyY

Answer (score 0):

use following function to insert data in DB

```
$data['col1']='value1';
$data['col2']='value2';
.
.
$data['coln']='valuen';

insert('table_name',$data);

    function Insert( $table, $condition )
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` SET ";
    $content = null;
    foreach ( $condition as $k => $v )
    {
        $v_str = null;
        if ( is_numeric($v) )
            $v_str = "'{$v}'";
        else if ( is_null($v) )
            $v_str = 'NULL';
        else
            $v_str = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($v) . "'";

        $content .= "`$k`=$v_str,";
    }
    $content = trim($content, ',');
    $sql .= $content;
    return $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```