# get data from url when multiple exist with same name

Tags: php, html, get

I have a form with checkboxes that posts data to the url for next page. I know this is not secure and is not being used in any project. This is only for learning purposes only.

I'm pushing tasks which are pulled from my database.

My url looks like this:

```
submitted.php?id=?12345
```

Depending on how many of the task checkboxes I check, I need it to push the IDs to next page.

here is my form:

```
<form action="Billing.php?id=<?PHP echo $customerid;?>" method="post">
        <?php $query = "SELECT * FROM Service"; 
               $result = mysqli_query($con,$query); 
               while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?> 
               <input type="checkbox" name="service" value="<?php echo $line['Service_ID']?>"><?php echo $line['Service_Type']?> <br> <?php } ?> 



        <input type="submit" name="next" value="Check Out" style="bottom:3%;Right:3%;position:absolute;background-color:#B2B2B2;font-weight:bold;border-style:double;border-color:black;float:right;" >
    </form>
    </div><!--serviclist-->
    <div id="cust">
            <h3>Customer Information</h3>
            <table style="left: 7%;right: 5%;top: 20%;position: absolute;">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:<input class="rightText" name="customername" type="text" value="<?PHP echo $name; ?> "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Make: <input name="make" type="text" value="<?PHP echo $make; ?>"></td><td>Model: <input class="rightText" name="model" type="text" value="<?PHP echo $model; ?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Color: <input name="color" type="text" value="<?PHP echo $color; ?>" ></td><td>VIN: <br><input class="rightText" name="VIN" type="text" value="<?PHP echo $vin; ?>" ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

basically im trying to get it to post my customer id and my services that were checked to next page.

Comment: you must use & instead of$

Comment: sry thats a typo the url contains & i have fixed question

Comment: use post method for this purpose.

Comment: see this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079435/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php-and-insert-all-r/23079715#23079715

Comment: im sorry i seem to have added a lot of confusion. ive included the form. its not pushing the url at all like i thought it was because i forgot to add method of post. its posting my customer id now but none of my tak ids that are checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you managed to end with this query string, but let's assume you have:

`index.php?asd=1&asd=2&asd=3`

The you can catch it via

```
var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Output
`string 'asd=1&asd=2&asd=3' (length=17)`

Then split it by `&` delimiter

```
var_dump(explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
0 => string 'asd=1' (length=5)
1 => string 'asd=2' (length=5)
2 => string 'asd=3' (length=5)
```

Then split by = to find key=>value pairs.

However, this approach I find very unattractive and inefficient.

If you have control over the checkbox names, then build the query string like:

```
index.php?asd[]=1&asd[]=2&asd[]=3
```

Then

```
var_dump($_GET['asd']);
```

will return array

```
array (size=3)
0 => string '1' (length=1)
1 => string '2' (length=1)
2 => string '3' (length=1)
```

Comment: please see form i posted. i did not ask question properly first time.

Comment: @Kenny you want `?id=12345` to become `?id=12345&id=1000&id=2000` right? It's not possible when using POST, also you do have using action="?id=$var" if $var contains only one ID, you don't expect it to be pushed. But, of course, if you rename your checkbox from `service` to `service[]`, you will recieve an array of values in `$_POST['service']`

Answer (score 1):

You wrote your url wrong, it should look like :

```
submitted.php?taskid[]=1&taskid[]=7
```

Answer (score 0):

put checkbox as an ARRAY,
example
input type="checkbox" name="taskid[]"      value="any value you like"

and in server side php, use a FOR-EACH LOOP to fetch all taskids

```
    <?php
$tasks = $_GET['taskid'];  
     foreach($tasks as $values)  
       {  
        // do your operations here  
          echo $values;  
         }
```